How to unit test logic under AG GRID gridApi function forEachNode
Trying to get my unit test coverage for this bit of code:
  processUpdates(input) {
    let request = [];
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(function (node) { // <--- How to mock/spy inside forEachNode
      if (input.has(data.id)) {
        request.push(this.createRequestRowUpdate(node, input));
      }
      this.someCoolService.saveMychanges(request).pipe(map(res => res as any)).subscribe(res => {
        //success 
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        //failure
      });
    });
  }

How can I set my test up so I can make some assertions on some of the code inside the forEachNode call on the gridApi?
example
expect(service['saveMychanges']).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
Reference
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-rowNodes-forEachNode
Stack and Versions
Angular 15
"jest": "^29.5.0"
"ag-grid-angular": "^25.3.0",
UPDATE
Forgot to show in my question how I was mocking my grid api
const mGridApi = {
  sizeColumnsToFit: function () {
  },
  setRowData: function () {
  },
  updateRowData: function () {
  },
  setFocusedCell: function () {
  },
  startEditingCell: function () {
  },
  showNoRowsOverlay: function () {
  },
  hideOverlay: function () {
  },
  refreshCells: function () {
  },
  setColumnDefs: function () {
  },
  getSelectedRows: function () {
    return [{ // some object definition }];
  },
  stopEditing: function () {
  },
  exportDataAsCsv: function () {
  },
  forEachNode: function () { // I'm guessing I have to give it some sort of mock here so that I can read under the call?
  },
  setSortModel: function () {
  }
};

Test
it('should call processUpdate', async () => {
   component['gridApi'] = mGridApi;
   jest.spyOn(component, 'processUpdate');
   jest.spyOn(component, 'createRequestRowUpdate');
   jest.spyOn(service, 'saveMychanges');

   component['processUpdate']('test data in here');
   expect(component['createRequestRowUpdate']).hasBeenCalledOnce()

Hope that helps explain the issue better

Have you considered extracting the inner function of the forEachNode and unit testing it directly rather than trying to test AG Grid itself?

Not sure I understand the advice. So AG grid is providing the api, forEachNode (right?) when I run the test it seems there is no implementation for the forEachNode function, so the whole thing is skipped by the test runner. I'm just wanting to give it something to run on and peek inside to make sure the method abc is called within the loop

Added some to the question to show my ag grip api mock. I think I need to figure out what to supply the forEachNOde mock so that I see what is happening under it.

Turns out all I needed to do was to give the mock an implementation of the method. Took a minute to wrap my head around how to do it but this is what I came up with,
In a beforeEach or the setup section of the test provide this implementation to the gridApi object
    component['gridApi']['forEachNode'] = jest.fn((callback) => {
      const mockNodes = [{ data: { id: 1, value: 'cheers-luv'}}]
      mockNodes.forEach(node => callback(node));
    })

You can supply more data object if you'd like the implementation to iterate more than once.
